# How to prevent JWT Django (all-auth) from changing token when its username is updated?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using all-auth / django-rest-auth for Authorization. When the User changes his/her username, Django (Django REST Framework) changes user's token and this makes user log-out from app; I set the app to logout if its user's token is invalid.

What I want to do is that even if user changes username, email, or any field in `User`, it keeps token.

Here is settings.py

```
REST_USE_JWT = True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

    # Facebook OAuth2
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookAppOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',

    # django-rest-framework-social-oauth2
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2',
)
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=30),
}

...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion:

1) Make username as some hash object (uuid) and create new field called **username_custom**,
(change your login and register views)

2) Prepare your mode as:
`USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'` so it is default username in Django

3) Never update default field **username** and your token will never change.

## Example

1) Use package for user model : https://github.com/jcugat/django-custom-user

2) Model example

## Model

```
class UserModel(AbstractEmailUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=False, db_index=True)

    username_custom = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        self.first_name = self.first_name.capitalize()
        self.last_name = self.last_name.capitalize()
        self.full_name = '{} {}'.format(self.first_name.capitalize(), self.last_name.capitalize())
        super(UserModel, self).save(force_insert, force_update)

    def clean(self):
        if UserModel.objects.filter(email=self.email, username_custom=self.username_custom).exists():
            raise ValidationError('User already exists!')
```

You can see there is new field **username_custom**.

Now rest api create user.

```
class UserRegister(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    authentication_classes = ()

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data

        # or you can check username_custom
        if UserModel.objects.filter(email=data['email']).exists():
            return Response(data={'success': False, 'msg': 'User with email already exists.'},
                            status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

        data['username'] = '%s' % uuid.uuid4()

        serializer = UserRegisterSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()

            token_data = UserModel.objects.get(email=serializer.data['email'])
            payload = jwt_payload_handler(token_data)
            token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)

            return Response(data={'success': True, 'user': serializer.data,
                                  'token': token_prefix + token}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


        return Response(data={'success': False, 'msg': serializer.errors},
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

## Serializer

```
class UserRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.UUIDField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('password', 'email', 'user_type', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username_custom',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = UserModel.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

        return user
```

You must preprare UPDATE method to check unique email field so you dont get 2 email in your DB, or username_custom whatever you want to be authorization.

## Login API

```
class UserLoginView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, email, password):

        # or you can check username_custom
        if not UserModel.objects.filter(email=email.lower()).exists():
            return Response(data={'success': False, 'msg': 'Email or password wrong!'},
                            status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        qv = UserModel.objects.get(email=email.lower())
        user = authenticate(username=qv.username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                token_data = UserModel.objects.get(id=user.id)
                payload = jwt_payload_handler(token_data)
                token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)

                return Response(data={'success': True,
                                  'token': token_prefix + token}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(data={'success': False, 'msg': 'Email or password wrong!'},
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: I think your suggestion is VERY good approach... How do we set USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'?? Could you have any example code or tutorial?

Comment: Yea ill make it for you.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!